# How to stop x11vnc from shutting down when I log out?

Tags: bash, cron, vnc

At boot I have

```
sudo x11vnc -xkb -noxrecord -forever -noxfixes -noxdamage -display :0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -usepw
```

run via init.d

It works and shows me the login prompt when I use a VNC Client, however if I the logout the VNC server gets shutdown and I have to SSH in to restart it, I found and modified a script that I think should work:

```
#!/bin/bash

if pgrep "x11vnc"
then
    echo "Running"
else
    echo "Stopped"
    sudo x11vnc -xkb -noxrecord -forever -noxfixes -noxdamage -display :0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -usepw
fi
```

and it does (its in /usr/local/bin/testvnc if I run it however my cron job:

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/testvnc
```

It says its been run cat var/log/syslog | grep vnc however it does NOT start the vnc.

Answer (score 2):

Same problem for me on Kubuntu 16.04.1, but your script given me an idea for a solution.

Create a service file for systemd:

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/x11vnc.service
```

this is my `x11vnc.service` file's:

```
[Unit]
Description=Start x11vnc at startup.
After=multi-user.target display-manager.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/x11vnc -auth /var/run/sddm/* -noxdamage -norepeat -rfbauth /home/x11vnc/passwd -display :0 -rfbport 5900 -shared -o /var/log/x11vnc.log'
Restart=always
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Set permissions for execute:

```
sudo chmod u+x /etc/systemd/system/x11vnc.service
```

Reload and activate script on systemd:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable x11vnc.service
```

**Important:** Be sure to not use the `-loop` and `-forever` options on the `x11vnc` command otherwise x11vnc will not be able to kill the process after a logout and systemd will not be able to restart the service.